# About a maximal inequality

Tags: probability, inequality

The exercise 21.21 of Billingsley (3rd Edition) asks the following:

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ be identically distributed variables with finite second moment. Show that $n^{-1/2}\max_{k\leq n}|X_k|\rightarrow_p 0$.

I have seen proofs and results in other books and papers showing that a sufficient condition for $\max_{k\leq n}|X_k|$ to be $o_p(n^{1/2})$ is: $E|X_k|^{2+\epsilon}<\infty$ for some $\epsilon>0$. The proof is a simple application of Markov's inequality: For any $C>0$, $P[\max_{k\leq n}|X_k|>C\sqrt{n}]\leq E[\max_{k\leq n}|X_k|^{2+\epsilon}]/(n^{1+\epsilon/2}C^{2+\epsilon})\leq E|X_k|^{2+\epsilon}/(n^{\epsilon/2}C^{2+\epsilon})\rightarrow 0$.

However, the condition in the exercise mentioned above only requires finite second moment. Could someone please explain how to prove the above exercise?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

You can prove this directly. If $F(t)$ is the cumulative distribution function of $|X_1|$ then cdf distribution of the max of $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ is $F^n(t)$. Since convergence weakly to a point mass implies convergence in probability, it suffices to show $F^n(t\sqrt{n})\rightarrow G(t)$ where $G(t)=0$ for $t<0$ and $G(t)=1$ for $t\geq 0$. You have:

$$F^n(t\sqrt{n})=(1-\mathbb{P}(|X_1|>t\sqrt{n}))^{n}.$$

For $t<0$ the result is trivial. For $t>0$, notice that it suffices to show $\mathbb{P}(|X_1|>t\sqrt{n})=o(1/n)$. This follows from the fact that $\mathbb{E}[|X_1|^2]=\int_0^\infty P(|X_1|^2> t)$, where since $P(|X_1|>t)$ is a monotonically decreasing function in $t$, you must have $P(|X_1|^2>t)=o(1/t)$ as $t\rightarrow\infty$, which means $P(|X_1|>t)=o(1/t^2)$, giving the desired conclusion.